# NBNS Query = ICMP Destination Unreachable

Tags: networking, wireshark, icmp

I am having some difficulties when I am trying to get the **NetBIOS Name** of a machine by it's **IP Address** with the command (On Windows) `nbtstat -A 192.168.1.1`, In this example I am trying to get the name of the Router.

**My problem is** that it doesn't work... :) **So...** I was curious enough to open Wireshark and see the traffic, and what I found out is - When My comuter is sending the NBNS Query, the target machine response with an `ICMP Destination Unreachable (Port Unreachable)` Packet.

[Wireshark capture of NBNS query process on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyYuu.png)

**My questions are:**

- Why does it happen?
- How can I fix it?

Keep in mind that I've tried the solution from here - https://www.microchip.com/forums/m374876.aspx, but it doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 1):

The router doesn't implement NetBIOS and therefore has no process listening on port 137.